# Calculating lacunae of MCP to calculate home range?

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS 2.18.26 and I am trying to calculate the home range of howler monkeys I was tracking. Using the AniMove plug in I have managed to produce Minimum Convex Polygons (MCPs). However, I would like to calculate the 'Lacunae' (Contiguous areas within the MCP that were not entered by the monkeys) and am struggling to find information on how to do this in QGIS.

I am attempting to replicate the method used by Ostro et al (1999) in 'A Geographic Information System Method for Estimating Home Range Size' which can be found here--> https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/72aa/0a32838490a106a3526c9bd017e978134492.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you can find some method from another home range analysis toolbox http://www.geo.uzh.ch/~sstein/ojhorae/horae_documentation_v1.2final.pdf. If not then the authors may be willing to help.

Comment: That nine-page scientific paper is nice as a supporting document, but please summarize what you're trying to achieve in the body of your question. And please use the full term at least once of any abbreviations you include.